# sed extracting pattern in osx

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I have the string `string[3]` and I'd like to extract `3` on OSX with sed.

These outputs nothing:

```
echo "string[3]" | sed -n 's/string\[\(\d+\)\]/\1/p'
echo "string[3]" | sed -n 's/string\[\(\d+\)\].*/\1/p'
```

While with https://regex101.com/r/l9gN1v/1 works..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `\d` is a PCRE pattern for digits, you can't use it in OSX *sed* that does not seem to support the `-P` option.

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For full [POSIX BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) compatibility, you'll have to use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` for digits (since `\d` is a PCRE extension, unsupported on *any* `sed`) and `{1,}` open interval instead of `+`:

```
$ echo "string[3]" | sed -n 's/string\[\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\]/\1/p'
3
```

If your `sed` supports POSIX ERE (and BSD `sed` should), you can activate ERE support with `-E` flag (simplifying the expression due to less escaping and the `+` operator support):

```
$ echo "string[3]" | sed -nE 's/string\[([0-9]+)\]/\1/p'
3
```

Comment: Thanks. I would only add that unless you use .* before and after, you will also have returned whatever is before and after. i.e.: sed -nE 's/.*string\[([0-9]+)\].*/\1/p' works for me

Comment: @JoeSlav That's true, didn't know you want to filter the complete line. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
 echo "string[3]" | sed -n 's/string\[\([0-9]\+\)\]/\1/p'
```

Comment: [`\+` is a GNU extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax), so I don't think this will work on OSX (assuming OSX uses BSD `sed`).

Answer (score 0):

The \d (from enhanced E?REs) does not appear to be available in sed, at least on osx.
If you try echo ‘d’ | sed ’s/\d/a/g’, you will get ‘a’, which is a hint.
Also, + is an ERE operator, so would require a -E option to sed.